# OpenCV set pixels with simillar value to specific value

Tags: python, opencv

I'm beginner in OpenCV and I'm trying to create image like this:

Original image

[image: Original image]

Desired result

[image: Desired result]

I tried iteraring through every pixel of image and then setting it on specific value, but that approach is very very slow.

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("window")
image = cv2.imread("lena.png",0)

w,h = image.shape

for i in range(0,w):
    for j in range(0,h):
        if (image[i,j] >= 0 and image[i,j] <= 50):
            image[i,j] = 25
        elif (image[i,j] > 50 and image[i,j] <= 100):
            image[i,j] = 75
        elif (image[i,j] > 100 and image[i,j] <= 150):
            image[i,j] = 125
        elif (image[i,j] > 150 and image[i,j] <= 200):
            image[i,j] = 175
        elif (image[i,j] > 200 and image[i,j] <= 255):
            image[i,j] = 225


cv2.imshow("window",image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Has anyone knows some method or approach for doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the order of the loops to outer=height and inner=width

Comment: opencv has a lookup-table function (LUT) which should be quite fast after creating the LUT once.

Comment: `image[image <= 200] = 25*((image[image <= 200] // 50) + 1); image[image > 200] = 225`

Comment: @drooze That is something I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to perform is known as image pooling. You can use skimage's block_reduce method

```
skimage.measure.block_reduce(image, block_size, func=<function sum>, cval=0)
```

> Down-sample image by applying function to local blocks

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce